# InvalidRegistration on sending push in php

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push notification on my android app but  I always received the *error* :

> "InvalidRegistration"

This is the tokens that I sent in the "*to*"

My code:-

```
 public function android_push($token, $load, $key) {

    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $token,
        'data' => $load
    );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $key,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields, true));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

My params:

```
   {"title":"Test","msg":"test"}
token: ["pid_58cc-6fed***"]
key:AA*****zEoEbsgPZCjK_umqrmgMZRkpyN7BAA5MNfGuojQP5olWIe1H_vzU8-9THNcB-CgZAjA6fwL72yE******6V7Cl-IObLDGwA6SqTopuK96begUtysy_cG8rc02vdIeYx****
```

result:

> {"multicast_id":4723735099133341876,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

Comment: `pid_*` does not look like a valid registration token to me, are you sure it is correct?

Comment: I do not know how to figure out whether it is right or not ؟